# Add calculated fields in a Pivot Table using LEFT() function

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a basic pivot table in Excel in which I want to add a calculated column, which describes `year`, and which is simply enough just the four leftmost characters from the `Sale Date` column.

Hence I do `[Select somewhere in pivot table]->Analyze->Fields, objects,..`

and then I use the settings:

Name: Year
Formula: =LEFT('Sale DATE',4)

but this gives the error that `Sale Date` cannot be found. But, `Sale Date` is added from the available columns in the report, and thus is not misspelled.

Does anyone have any idea?

I've tried to use `;` instead of `,` in the formula as I'm using a European version of Excel but then I got the same error as well.

> EDIT

I've tried to do some basic calculations with the same approach (for instance creating a new field which is the Product of a field and a constant) and it has worked fine. Perhaps I'm using the wrong formula language, or that Pivot tables does not permit "advanced" formulae?

Comment: @pnuts         I just want to find the `Year` from a `Sale Date` (of appaerence yyyymmdd), so for me a simply `LEFT(Sale Date,4)` or `Year('Sale Date')` would suffice. From all tutorials I've seen, Pivot Table never has any kind of function in its calculations. Is that not supported? I want to find the year so I later can create a Pivot Chart using all months on the x-axis and have lines corresponding to total sales per month and specific year.

Answer (score 0):

As pnuts says in his comment, Calculated Fields are not the way to go here. Instead, use the 'Group Selection' option to group by Years and Months:

[image]

...and then your PivotCharts will let you display the result like so:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried to modify my underlying SQL data source to convert the dates from a string to data type `Date`. I then got an error of it being `Unable to Group`, which I've understood is due to the date column not being of date data type in Excel. I therefore tried to insert the `date column` as a row filter in Excel, right click the column and go to `Date -> Text to Columns -> .. -> To Date`. This will create a new column of values which I cannot replace my original column with, as I then got an error of adjusting the PivotTable.